# How to satisfy else condition in test class dont get it

Tags: unit-test

i have a simple class below

```
public with sharing class Additionoftwonum1

{ 
    public void sum()
    { 
    integer a=3;
    integer b=4;
    integer c= 8;
    boolean b1 = false;
    if(c!=a+b)
    {
    c = 7;
    system.debug(c);
    }
    else
    {
        c-=1;
        system.debug(c);
    }
    }
}

I wrote test class for this simple class but not able to cover else statement

@isTest
public class TestAdditionoftwonum1
{
    static testmethod void adddataFetch()
    {
        integer c = 7;
        Additionoftwonum1 nm1 = new Additionoftwonum1();
        nm1.sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: As all Integer variables are part of Sum method, you can't be able control their values. Hence every time If condition will get passed when you try invoke to sum method in test class. Instead, define Integer variables outside of Sum method and then you can able to control those variables inside Test class.

Comment: additional to @Devendra. instead of multiple if else condition make it to single line(conditional operator). c=(c!=a+b)?c+1:c-1;

Comment: hi davendra i have same scenario in another class this is just a trial i just want to know how to cover the local method variables values which is under if else statement i dont able to cover because whenver i call the method in which local variable declare in if else condition are not cover do you have an any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your class it NEVER goingo to use the else statement.

You're using local variable `a`, `b` and `c` to make the evaluation and they're reset everytime you call the method.

Also, you have no way to change their values and the `Integer c` on your test class is not passed on to your method.

There are lots of ways of achieving what you want. You can take a look at the one below, for example:

```java
public with sharing class Additionoftwonum1{ 

    public Integer a = 3;
    public Integer b = 4;
    public Integer c;

    public void sum(){ 

        if(c!=a+b){
            c = 7;
        }

        else{
            c-=1;
        }

        system.debug(c);
    }
}

@isTest
public class TestAdditionoftwonum1{
    static testmethod void adddataFetch(){
        Additionoftwonum1 nm1 = new Additionoftwonum1(); //a == 3, b == 4, c == null
        nm1.c = 32;  //a == 3, b == 4, c == 32
        nm1.sum();   //goes through if c == 7 
        nm1.sum();   //goes through else c == 6
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks fernando but its not working

Comment: oops, sorry @Bonny , I just edited my answer. Can you take a look?

Comment: hi Fernando i know if i declare the variable outside the  method within the class i can cover then if else easily my question is how to cover if else. If variable declare in a method not within the class?

Comment: You can't. If the variable it's declared inside the method it's only evaluated when the method runs. You either have to declare the variable outside and edit it or you can pass it to the method as a parameter.